# Terraform expire resource

Tags: terraform, certificate

In terraform I need to call an api to get a certificate and store that in a resource.

However, this certificate is only valid for 12 months.

How do I configure terraform to detect it needs to fetch a new certificate to replace the existing value?

It is not possible to fetch every time, due to cost.

The only resource I can find that seems to deal with expiration is https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/self_signed_cert#automatic-renewal but not usable in this case since the cerficate is made remotely.

Comment: Which (cloud) provider are you using?

Comment: Does it matter? Its a custom certificate from an external provider

Comment: It sure does, because there might be API calls which you could use periodically to query the expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

Just make a dummy certificate and add dependency on that.

```
resource "tls_private_key" "dummy_pem" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 1024
}

resource "tls_self_signed_cert" "dummy_timeout" {
  private_key_pem = tls_private_key.dummy_pem.private_key_pem

  //9 months
  validity_period_hours = 6570

  //dummy values
  allowed_uses = ["server_auth"]
}

resource "whatever" "whatever" {
  depends_on = [tls_self_signed_cert.dummy_timeout]
}
```

when the dummy certificate expires, our resource will be invalidated and recreated

Comment: This `depends_on` only tells Terraform that it must deal with changes to `tls_self_signed_cert.dummy_timeout` before changes to `whatever.whatever`. It doesn't change what actions Terraform would plan for `whatever.whatever`. If you have made your system work as you wanted then it is _something else_ in your configuration that made it work; `depends_on` alone is not sufficient.